# Wann wird "bis auf" inklusiv, wann exklusiv verwendet?

Tags: meaning, usage

Ich habe mehrmals die Situation erlebt, dass jemand einen Satz mit "bis auf" verwendet und mir nicht klar ist, ob eine einschließende oder ausschließende Bedeutung gemeint ist.

- Zum Beispiel bei einem Arzt: **"Ziehen Sie sich bitte bis auf die Unterwäsche aus."** Soll in diesem Fall die Unterwäsche ausgezogen werden oder darf sie anbehalten werden?
- **"Ich habe das Gebäck bis auf den letzten Keks leer gegessen."** Wurden hier alle Kekse gegessen oder ist noch einer vorhanden?
- **"Er hat sich bis auf die Knochen blamiert."** Wurden die Knochen auch blamiert oder sind sie als einziges nicht blamiert worden?

Der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/bis_auf) kennt beide Verwendungen:

> *inklusiv*: **Die Halle war bis auf den letzten Platz voll.** (Letzter Platz belegt)
>
> *exklusiv*: **Bis auf die Uroma waren alle gekommen.** (Uroma nicht gekommen)

Ich bilde mir ein, dass der inklusive Satz zu einem exklusiven wird, wenn ich die Satzteile verschiebe:

> *exklusiv?*: **Bis auf den letzten Platz war die Halle voll.** (Letzter Platz nicht belegt?)

Hängt die Bedeutung allgemein von der Satzstellung ab? Lässt sich eine Regel formulieren, wann die exklusive, wann die inklusive Bedeutung gemeint ist?

Comment: Gute Frage, und ich habe auch keine Antwort. Möglicherweise beschreibt "bis auf" nur eine Grenze, und inklusiv/exklusiv bleibt offten. Bei "bis auf die Knochen blamiert" habe ich allerdings das Bild "so tief blamiert, dass es bis zu den Knochen geht (also sehr tief)" im Kopf. Die Knochen selbst können sich nicht blamieren, insofern spielt inklusiv/exklusiv hier keine Rolle.

Comment: Ja, das Bild das bei "....bis auf die Knochen" verwendet wird, ist eine tiefe körperliche Verletzung, eine Wunde, die die Knochen freilegt. Dieses Bild/der damit verbundene Schmerz wird auf die Blamage übertragen, um die Intensität des Gefühls auszudrücken.

Comment: Gibt es denn außer "bis auf der/die/das letzte ..." und ggf. schwer zu interpretierende idiomatische Wendungen ("bis auf die Knochen") überhaupt Beispiele für inklusive Verwendung?

Comment: @Matthias: Ist "Das muss bis Oktober beantwortet sein" inklusive oder exklusive Verwendung? M.E. ist das offen und kann oft nur durch Kontextwissen beantwortet werden.

Comment: @user unknown Wo ist da das "auf "? Hier war nach "bis auf " gefragt worden.

Comment: Bei der Sache mit der Unterwäsche: "bis auf" ist hier als Ortsangabe gemeint. Es wird klargestellt, dass man sich "bis auf die Unterwäsche herunter" auszieht, also, was die letzte Schicht ist "bis auf die man sich ablegt". Es ist keine Mengenqualifikation im mathematischen Sinne wie die anderen Fälle und muss getrennt betrachtet werden!

Comment: @Matthias: Du meinst es liegt am "auf"? Meine ich nicht. Etwas, das bis Sonntag fertig sein muss könnte bis Sonntag früh oder spät fertig sein - da hat man m.E. das gleiche Problem.

Comment: @userunknown Ich meine vor allem, daß Chris ausdrücklich nach "bis auf" gefragt hat und daß das was anderes ist als "bis". Und ich habe dann nach weiteren Beispielen für inklusive Verwendung von "bis auf" gefragt. Da ist eine Antwort, die sich auf "bis" bezieht, schlicht nicht hilfreich.

Comment: @Matthias: Ich finde das sehr hilfreich, denn die von user unknown angedeutete Frage ist doch: Ist es sinnvoll, das speziell für "bis auf" zu diskutieren, oder ist "bis auf" einfach nur ein Spezialfall des allgemeineren Ausdrucks "bis", der ebenso unklar definiert ist?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Auch 8 Jahre später hat hier immer noch niemand Beispiele für eine eindeutig inklusive Verwendung von "bis auf" gebracht, die nicht in eine der beiden von mir genannten Kategorien fallen. Für "ebenso unklar definiert" sehe ich da keine Grundlage.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**These**:
Meiner Auffassung nach ist aus der Position im Satz keine Schlussfolgerung zu ziehen, ob es exklusive oder inklusive gemeint ist. Der einzige Unterschied, den die Stellung im Satz ausmacht, ist Betonung.

**Argumentation**:
Häufig ergibt sich die Bedeutung aus dem Kontext. Das Beispiel aus der anderen Antwort kann nur auf eine Art und Weise verstanden werden:

> Das Konzert war bis auf wenige Zuhörer leer.
>   Bis auf wenige Zuhörer war das Konzert leer.

In beiden Fällen ist es synonym zu "Mit Ausnahme weniger Zuhörer".

Vergleiche doch auch mal die Varianten mit der Uroma.

> Alle waren gekommen, bis auf die Uroma.
>   Bis auf die Uroma waren alle gekommen.

Beide Varianten sagen eindeutig, dass die Uroma nicht da ist. Ich sehe absolut keinen Spielraum für anderweitige Interpretation.

In anderen Sätzen ist es schwierig rauszuhören und die "bis auf"-Formulierung ist hier schwammig. Und dennoch ist es meinem Empfinden nach im Kontext oft eindeutig. Dass die Position wumpe ist, sieht man ganz offensichtlich.

> Ziehen Sie sich bitte bis auf die Unterwäsche aus.
>   Bis auf die Unterwäsche ziehen Sie sich bitte aus.

Mal davon abgesehen, dass die zweite Variante sowieso etwas hakelig klingt (zumindest ungewohnt), denke ich, dass hier nahezu immer "Mit Ausnahme der Unterwäsche" gemeint ist, da das auch dem Regelfall entspricht. Wenn anderweitig gemeint, dann wird der Arzt das schon sagen.

In der Tat schwierig finde ich es in dem Beispiel:

> Die Halle war bis auf den letzten Platz voll.
>   Bis auf den letzten Platz war die Halle voll.

Hier kann tatsächlich beides gemeint sein. In beiden Varianten. Besser ist es hier "abgesehen von" oder "einschließlich" zu verwenden. Aber wohlbemerkt ist üblicherweise "einschließlich" gemeint. (Daher auch im Duden als Beispiel für "einschließlich" aufgelistet.)
Wie es wirklich gemeint ist, kann dennoch nur der Sprecher wissen. Und wenn es der Kontext nicht erahnen lässt, sollte eine klarere Formulierung gewählt werden, beziehungsweise nachgefragt werden.

**Lange Rede, kurzer Sinn:**
Position egal. Meistens aus dem Kontext erschließbar. Im Zweifel nachfragen oder Wortwahl überdenken.

Comment: Ich möchte meinen, dass im letzten Beispiel eine Sprechpause den unüblicheren Fall suggeriert: "Die Halle war–bis auf den letzten Platz–voll. == "Die Halle war–mit Ausnahme des letzten Platzes–voll." Dabei wird nicht nur eine Pause eingelegt, sondern die eingefügte Phrase wird mit einer etwas dumpferen Tonlage gesprochen. Das füge ich der Antwort aber nicht bei, weil ich mir nicht sicher bin, ob ich mir das gerade nur einbilde. Andersrum mag ich auch glauben, dass eine Betonung von "bis" in einer leicht höheren Tonlage die gängigere Interpretation "einschließlich" bestätigt.

Comment: Wir präzisieren das vermutlich unbewußt, indem wir sagen *Die Halle war bis auf **einen** letzten Platz voll*.

Comment: Das ist doch Quatsch! Wie oft wird die Floskel verwendet, und immer soll ausgerechnet ein Platz noch frei sein? Das ist wirklich Unfug bis zum Umfallen!

Comment: @userunknown Falls du mich mit deinem Kommentar addressierst... Ich zitiere mich mal selbst: "Aber wohlbemerkt ist üblicherweise "einschließlich" gemeint." Also *alle* Plätze sind belegt und keiner mehr frei.

Comment: @Em1: Schon der Zweifel ist strafbar. ;)

Answer (score 5):

Etwaige Satzumstellungen ändern nichts an der Bedeutung der Beispiele mit den Hallenplätzen und den Keksen. In beiden Fällen liegt in meinen Augen ein inklusiver Gerbauch vor.

Ihnen gemein ist, dass sie eine Menge gleicher Entitäten beschreiben. Das Objekt in `bis auf den letzten Keks/Platz` ist unbestimmt.

Eine ausschließende Formulierung bedarf eines Numerales oder einer anderen näheren Bestimmung:

> Ich habe das Gebäck bis auf einen Keks aufgegessen.
>   Die Halle war bis auf zwei Plätze voll - unsere.
>   Die Halle war bis auf ein paar Plätze voll.

Bei Kommasetzung (Beistrichen) scheint es schon etwas schwieriger zu sein:

> Die Halle war, bis auf den letzten Platz, voll.

Aber auch hier überwiegt bei mir die inklusive Interpretation.

Im Gegensatz zu der ursprünglichen Form dieses Beispieles kommen in jenen mit dem Familienfest und dem Ausziehen ganz bestimmte Objekte vor, nämlich *die Unterwäsche* und *die Uroma*. Diese beiden sind hingegen exklusiv.

Nehmen wir eine sehr große Familie, in der es ganz viele Tanten gibt:

> Es sind alle bis auf die letzte Tante gekommen.

In dieser Variante sind wiederum alle gekommen. Parallel dazu:

> Ziehen sie sich bitte bis auf das letzte Kleidungsstück aus.

Die Person wird sich wohl ganz ausziehen müssen. Es scheint demnach, als könne man die Ein- oder Ausschließlichkeit durch das Abwandeln der Objektbestimmung (nach *bis auf*) beeinflussen.

---

<sup>Um sagen zu können, ob `bis auf die Knochen` ex- oder inklusiv zu verstehen ist, müsste man wohl um die Herkunft der Wendung wissen.</sup>

Comment: Dem stimme ich zu, das entspricht auch meinem Sprachempfinden. Wenn ein _konkretes Objekt_ (bis auf ... "Ihre Unterwäsche", "unsere Uroma (Frida)", "meine Knochen") gemeint ist, ist es _exklusiv_ zu verstehen. Wenn ein generisches, also _beliebiges Objekt unter vielen_ gemeint ist (bis auf ... "letzten Platz", "letzter Keks" ist es _inklusiv_ zu verstehen. Im letzteren Fall macht erst ein Numeral die Bedeutung exklusiv, wie auch in der Antwort gesagt.

Answer (score 2):

Also um es mal klar zu definieren:
Mathematisch ist ein "bis" grundsätzlich exclusive (mit ausnahme es steht da inklusive bis)
Bei Zeitangaben oft fälschlich eingesetzt ich bin bis 20:00 Uhr zu Hause, heisst, dass ich ab spätestens 20:00 Uhr zu hause bin. Das heisst, dass wenn die Uhr von 19:59:59 auf 20:00:00 "umschaltet" muss ich schon zu Hause sein um meine Initielle Ansage zu erfüllen.

Ich bin bis zum 01.09.2020 fest eingestellt -> der 01.09.2020 ist der erste Tag, an dem ich nicht mehr eingestellt bin.

Problematisch ist, dass sich fälschlicherweise eingebürgert hat, dass wenn man "Bis zu dem Tag.." sagt, genaugenommen meint "inkl. bis zu dem Tag..." meint es aber schlicht und ergreifend falsch gemeint ist :-)

Sooo Einfach ist das^^
LG,
Matte

Answer (score -5):

Ja, die Bedeutung hängt im Allgemeinen von der Stellung im Satz ab.

Wenn Du sagst "Bis auf …" ist es **exklusiv**, wodurch du eine *Ausgrenzung* des Objektes vornimmst.
Wie Du sagtest:

> **Bis auf** den letzten Platz war die Halle voll.

Das heißt, dass der letzte Platz **nicht belegt** war.

Auf der anderen Seite, wenn *bis auf* mittig im Satz steht, ist es inklusiv:

> Das Konzert war *bis auf* wenige Zuhörer leer.

Hier sind fast keine Zuschauer vorhanden, aber es sind welche vorhanden.

Allgemein betrachtet kann man also sagen:

- "**Bis auf**" am Anfang eines Satzes ist eine Exklusion
- "*Bis auf*" im Satz ist eine Inklusion

Um nun auch noch auf Deine Sätze zu reagieren:

> - Ziehen Sie sich bitte ***bis auf*** die Unterwäsche aus: Unterwäsche bleibt angezogen
> - Ich habe das Gebäck **bis auf** den letzten Keks leer gegessen: Alle Kekse wurden gegessen
> - Er hat sich bis auf die Knochen blamiert: Die Knochen wurden auch "blamiert" (man kann so etwas eigentlich nicht sagen)

Bei der Unterwäsche und bei den Knochen gibt es allerdings noch einen Sonderfall, da diese als Ebenen dargestellt werden können. Daher ist bei der Unterwäsche eine **Exklusion**.

Comment: Ich glaube nicht, dass diese "Regel" irgendwie hilfreich ist: du hast hier selbsst schon Gegenbeispiele gefunden. Davon abgesehen ist dein erstes Beispiel "...bis auf den letzten Platz voll" meinem Empfinden nach in den meisten Fällen inklusiv, soll heißen alle Plätze sind voll, es gibt keine freien Plätze mehr.

Comment: Ich glaube auch nicht, daß das stimmt. Um den Gegenbeispielen von Em1 noch eines hinzuzufügen: "Die Halle war bis auf den letzten Platz voll." (Inklusion) vs. "Die Halle war bis auf den Platz links außen hinter der Säule voll." (Exklusion) Gleiche Satzstellung, bis auf Attribute gleiches Vokabular - andere Bedeutung.