# Understanding 'bis auf': excluding/including

Tags: meaning

> **This question also has an answer here (in German):**
> *[Wann wird "bis auf" inklusiv, wann exklusiv verwendet?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15536/wann-wird-bis-auf-inklusiv-wann-exklusiv-verwendet)*

I'm fairly confused about the meaning of 'bis auf.'

My dictionary tells me it means 'excluding' or 'except for.'

But then I read a sentence like

> Die Armenier wollen „Recognition“, keine Straßen zu denen, die sie bis
> auf das letzte Kind vernichten wollten und das auch noch leugnen.

in reference to the Turk genocide against Armenian. What do they wanted kill all including the last kid, or kill all excluding the last kid?

Other sentences that 'bis auf' seems to get the meaning of 'including' for me:

> Bewohner des Ortes bis auf das letzte Kind liquidiert.
>
> Und Gott befahl Israel, im Land Kanaan, alle zu töten bis auf das letzte Kind

Comment: Ich bin schwach in Zeichensetzung. Kannst Du das Armenierzitat noch mal auf Kommas prüfen? Ich denke: "Die Armenier wollen *Recognition*, keine Straßen zu denen, die sie bis auf das letzte Kind vernichten wollten und das auch noch leugnen."

Answer (score 6):

"[bis auf](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/bis_auf)" literally means something close to "until", or "up to".

"until x" can obviously mean "anything *including* x" and "anything *excluding* x". Which of both notations is the case, can only be derived from context. The English expression "up to" has the same semantic problem.